# Unable to access a column of a dataframe in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

i have my data and there is a column name User Name and I am unable to read that column in dataframe it gives me

```
KeyError: 'User Name'
```

the reason behind this is, in my excel , in the first cell the header is User Name but both the words i.e User and Names are written in different lines, Just like User (alt+Enter) Name. I want to handle this problem in pandas.

I have added an image of the column

[image]

I want to it to be like -

| User Name |
| --- |

Please help me to get my desired O/P. Please let me know , if I have made clear what my problem is.

Comment: `print(df.columns)` to see the name of the column because it is not `'User Name'` and then rename the column to whatever you want: `df = df.rename(columns={'old_col_name': 'new_col_name'})`

Comment: Probably replace newline character `\n` with whitespace.

Comment: thanks both of you for your suggestions :)....